# Locks in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, locks

I am using SQLAlchemy to do transactions into PosgreSQL db using Python application.
I don't know how to use locks in SQLAlchemy.

Anybody can help me to use locks in SQLAlchemy.

I am facing a problem as follows,

While running two instances of a an application parallel, it tries to insert rows into a same table. Sometimes I am getting error of duplicate primary key. Can I resolve this using lock concept?

Best Regards,
Suji

Comment: How are you constructing your primary key? Your issue seems unrelated to locking in that you're trying to insert the same row twice.

Answer (score 1):

In order to explicitly use locks you can utilize the `engine` or the `connection` to issue raw `SQL` to the database:

```py
engine.execute('LOCK TABLES tablename WRITE')
# do your stuff....
engine.execute('UNLOCK TABLES')
```